# check if any realm instances is running or not before deleting the database

Tags: android, realm

How to check all realm instances are closed or not?

I want to check if any realm instances is running or not before deleting the database.. I want to know how many instances are open.

I've this

```
getGlobalInstanceCount(myRealm.getConfiguration());


 public static int getGlobalInstanceCount(RealmConfiguration configuration){
    //How do I convert the configuration to int? so that I return the number of open stores
    return  **;
}
```

I do not know how to convert RealmConfiguration to Int. to return the number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to safe delete realm database..

1. remove all listeners if you're using.

   ```
   try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
       realm.removeAllChangeListeners();
       realm.executeTransaction(Realm::deleteAll);
   }
   ```

   2. if you want to delete specific class/table

      ```
       try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {

          realm.executeTransaction(innerRealm -> {

          innerRealm.where(DatabaseClass.class)
                  .findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();

          // or

          innerRealm.delete(DatabaseClass.class);
      });
      }
      ```

By doing so, this will create realm instance on current thread and close the same instance.
`try-with-resourses` closes realm instance automatically.

> Realm doesn't provide technique to close all realm instance at once. You can only obtain instance count.

- Global Instance and local instance count

  ```
  try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
     int globalInstance = Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount(realm.getConfiguration());

     int localInstance = Realm.getLocalInstanceCount(realm.getConfiguration());

  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

It's really just `Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount(realmConfiguration)`.

Comment: Is there any way to close all realm instances which were accidentally opened in another thread?

Comment: Well, you can only close the Realm on the thread that opened it... :|